# Swift 3 - Background image issue for my UIViewController in landscape mode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

First, this was done programmatically and not in Storyboards.

I am using a background image for my UIViewController. It looks fine in portrait mode but because my image is not wide enough for landscape mode, the image becomes doubled (the same image is shown twice, side by side) when the device is tilted to landscape mode. Is there a way to switch to a different background image if the device is rotated to landscape mode in order to avoid this issue?

Please note: I am trying to do this without having to create an entirely new UIViewController for landscape mode.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "backgroundimage.png")!)


    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    view.addSubview(inputsContainerView)
    view.addSubview(loginRegisterButton)
    view.addSubview(profileImageView)
    view.addSubview(loginRegisterSegmentedControl)

    setupInputsContainerView()
    setupLoginRegisterButton()
    setupProfileImageView()
    setupLoginRegisterSegmentedControl()
}
```

Comment: Don't use your image as a "pattern." Add a `UIImageView`... set the constraints to pin it to all four sides... set the Content Mode to either Fill, AspectFill, ApectFit, Center, etc... whatever gives you satisfactory appearance.

Comment: yep as @DonMag says, use `UIImageView` instead. and also you can check the `orientation` to see whether the `mode` is `landscape` or `portrait`.

Answer (score 1):

Use **UIImageView** to set a background image instead of using **UIColor(patternImage:)** method. See the below code snippet

```
var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    backgroundImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y: self.view.frame.origin.y, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
    backgroundImageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
  }
```

I have created a backgroundImageView and set the image to that view. In order to handle portrait and landscape mode, autoresizingMask parameter is also set